# How do I use the latest version of jQuery and get back the '$' for jQuery in RichFaces?

Tags: jquery, jsp, jsf, richfaces, facelets

RichFaces 3.3.3 comes baked in with jQuery 1.3.2 and prototype and scriptaculous as well.

How can I try and use the latest version of jQuery?
Can I use the Google CDN one?

Also the `$()` object is defaulted to prorotype and to use jQuery I have to do `jQuery()`

is there a way to get back the $ for jQuery without breaking RichFaces?

UPDATE:
You can use multiple versions of jQuery side by side. For now, I've gone ahead and used the version that comes baked with RichFaces.

Comment: How do you use the version that comes with RichFaces..My problem is I am using Jquery in my JSF..I am not using the <rich:jQuery> component..How can it automatically read the js file even without using jQuery component provided by richFaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $ with jQuery without breaking RichFaces by wrapping your jQuery code in this manner:

```
(function($) {
  /* your jQuery code can use $() here */
})(jQuery);
```