# Change the JQuery version used in richfaces

Tags: jquery, richfaces

I am using richfaces 3_3_3.Final, and I wan't to use the latest jQuery `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js`, but it seems to have conflicts.

Richfaces already load a jQuery version (witch is not the suitable version, seems to be 1.3.2) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/project/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/jquery/jquery.js.jsf">
```

Can I use the latest version for my Javascript process, and allow RichFaces to use its own version, and how?

Is jQuery.noConflict()  a good area of research ?

Comment: @Moin Zaman [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881953/how-do-i-use-the-latest-version-of-jquery-and-get-back-the-for-jquery-in-rich) tells we can use multiple versions of jQuery side by side, but doesn't say how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `jQuery.noConflict` is a good start, but since the "other library" you are using is also jQuery, there will probably be complications.

When you load jQuery, it defines `$` and `jQuery` as global variables. Using `.noConflict` will "relinquish control of the `$` variable" - meaning whatever `$` was before, it will be set to again. If v1.3.2 is loaded first and you load latest pack (1.6.4 as of right now) next, `.noConflict` will make `$` refer to v1.3.2 but `jQuery` will still refer to 1.6.4.

Basically, you need to alias jQuery before you load the latest pack. [See my fiddle used to simulate your situation](http://jsfiddle.net/RHMWH/1/) (also pasted below).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //alias v.1.3.2
    var $132 = $;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //alias v1.6.4
    var $164 = $, jQuery164 = $;

    //reset original variables to v1.3.2
    $ = jQuery = $132;

    console.log("v1.3.2: ", $().jquery, jQuery().jquery)
    console.log("v1.6.4: ", $164().jquery, jQuery164().jquery)

    $('div')      //selected using v1.3.2
    $164('div')   //selected using v1.6.4
</script>
```

After loading 1.6.4, you need to alias it and set `$` and `jQuery` back to the 1.3.2 objects. This doesnt use `.noConflict` becuase it essentially does the same thing. RichFaces will continue to work using 1.3.2 and you will write your code against the aliased 1.6.4 version. In my fiddle, that means using `$164` instead of using `$`. I hope that makes sense. I am sure the fiddle will be clearer.

---

Finally, it is fine to develop code using `jquery-latest.pack.js` but you shouldn't ever use that on your production website. The reason is because at some point in the future, jQuery will be updated. If you are loading the latest pack, those updates may break the functionality of your site without you even knowing it. It's safer to just pick a version and stick to it, only upgrading only when you confirmed that your site will continue to function properly.

Comment: I understand the answer but I can't implement the solution. There is a conflict with Richfaces (extendeddatatables can't be displayed)

Comment: That sounds like it is a different problem than you originally mentioned - or at least I dont see the connection. How are you including RichFaces and jQuery?

Comment: My project is using JSF1.2/Richfaces (with maven). When I test to include another  version of jQuery, I add `<script type="text/javascript"` in the header...

Comment: I accept the solution because you explain me how to use 2 versions of jQuery side by side, but the problem still exists : use in `$` version 1.6.4, and let Richfaces use 1.3.2 ...

Comment: @Jean-Charles - I was having the same issue with `<rich:extendedDataTable>`... Using `jQuery.noConflict()` solved it for me.